# What is the largest possible number of distinct gcds in a 3x3 grid?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Consider the following table:
\begin{array}{r|cc}
\gcd & 20 & 21 & 22 \\ \hline
54 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\
55 & 5 & 1 & 11 \\
56 & 4 & 7 & 2
\end{array}
This is $\gcd(x,y)$ for $x\in\{20\mathbin{..}22\}$ and $y\in\{54\mathbin{..}56\}$. Note that there are seven different $\gcd$ values: $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $7$, and $11$. My question is: can we go above seven? In other words:

**What is the largest possible number of distinct values of $\gcd(x,y)$ for $x\in\{a\mathbin{..}a+2\}$ and $y\in\{b\mathbin{..}b+2\}$, for some pair of positive integers $a$ and $b$?**

So far I haven't been able to go above seven, but I suspect we can go all the way up to nine.

(We can easily generalize this question for grid sizes other than $3\times3$.)

Comment: Bonus points for finding the _smallest_ values of $a$ and $b$ that produce eight and nine values.

Comment: @ThePhoenix Ahh, of course. (I wonder what the smallest is, then.)

Comment: Oh, $\{20\mathbin{..}22\}\times\{55\mathbin{..}57\}$ would have worked for seven as well!

Comment: To get $9$ distinct entries, some constraints that come to mind: (1) No primes, which would give three entries of $1$. (2) At most three even numbers, of which two are divisible by $4$. I don't think you can get four distinct even GCDs without a lot of finagling, and possibly not at all. (3) Both triples must have a multiple of $3$, so exactly one box on the grid will be a multiple of three. ------ So I think you want one triple centered on a multiple of $4$, with two composite odd numbers on either side, and the other triple centered on an odd composite number.

Comment: That's too long to add these further thoughts: $56$ is the smallest multiple of $4$ with no prime on either side. $(3,7,11,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53)$ are the primes that block lower multiples of $4$. The next available ones are $(64,76,116,120 \dots)$. ------ Also, we can have just one pair of coprime integers across the two triples.

Comment: $(a,b) =(114, 435)$ yields 8.

Comment: $(a,b) =(1274, 2260)$ yields 9.

Comment: @GohP.iHan Is that the only solution where both are smaller than 2500?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger These are the solutions under $2500$: $(740,2014), (986,2260), (1034, 2254), (1274, 2260)$.

Comment: @Théophile Interesting that $2260$ shows up twice!

Comment: Given that the original question is answered, the natural follow-up might be, what is the smallest $a$ for which there is a good pair $(a,b)$? For example, removing the ceiling of $2500$, I have found other solutions like $(154, 24738)$.

Comment: @Théophile That's definitely interesting because of the infinite search space.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes, there are some numbers that show up repeatedly, e.g., $(154, 24738), (154, 33759), (154, 43615), \ldots ?$ Presumably there will be infinite families like this.

Comment: Darn, I started programming too late! I also have $(740,2014)$ as the smallest solution. It seems my assumption about just $3$ even numbers was incorrect; the smallest pair with an odd number is $(559, 2924)$, and the smallest with two odd numbers is $(1825,4233)$. In fact, that's the *only* one below $10 000$ with two odd numbers. The smallest sum of GCDs (below $10 000$) is $(208 ,8930)$, with GCDs $(1,2,3,4,10,11,13,14,19)$.

Comment: Searching a bit, I'm going to extend @Théophile's conjecture: if a triplet can be used in one solution, it can be used in infinitely many solutions. Solutions seem sparser for smaller numbers and especially for odd numbers. An especially odd find: Every solution with $a=4235=5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11^2$ seems to produce the same GCDs (though not necessarily in the same order).

Comment: Finally, the smallest triples that have solutions are $(n, n+1, n+2)$ where $n \in \{154, 208, 220, 230,258 \cdots \}$. I suspect it is not a coincidence that these are the first five values for which $(n, n+n, n+2)$ have $7$ distinct prime factors among them (with only $2$ repeated. The smallest odd solution at $(559,560,561)$ has eight distinct prime factors among the three values. **Conjecture**: For a triple to be part of a solution, it must have $7$ distinct prime factors total if even, $8$ if odd. This would explain why semiprimes seem to be almost nowhere.

Comment: Good points all @ThePhoenix. I wasn't intending to claim anything about $x=4235$, though I see my wording was pretty strong. I merely meant that as an oddity, up to $10^8$ there weren't any other values.

Comment: Tacking on: of **course** the first counterexample is at $10608554$, just above $10^8$.